# standardStylesheets attribute doesn't work properly

Tags: css, visualforce

I can't get it work as it should.

The code rendered even for an empty page:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" standardController="Opportunity">

</apex:page>
```

Includes:

```
<link class="user" href="/sCSS/35.0/sprites/1450809186000/Theme3/default/gc/zen-componentsCompatible.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link class="user" href="/sCSS/35.0/sprites/1450809186000/Theme3/default/gc/elements.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link class="user" href="/sCSS/35.0/sprites/1450809186000/Theme3/default/gc/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link class="user" href="/sCSS/35.0/sprites/1448894026000/Theme3/gc/dStandard.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link class="user" href="/sCSS/35.0/sprites/1450809186000/Theme3/default/gc/extended.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link class="user" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,200,300,600,700,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: What if you try it with showheader="false"?

Comment: Yes! It works! It should be documented somewhere ... I can accept it if you write answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Suppressing the Salesforce User Interface and Styles](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_styling_suppressing_salesforce_stylesheets.htm)
 It will only work if you also disable the header by setting `showheader="false"`.

> standardStylesheets—Set to false, along with setting showHeader to
>   false, to suppress the inclusion of the style sheets that support the
>   Salesforce visual design. When you suppress the standard style sheets,
>   your page is completely unstyled, except for your own style sheets.